# Acceder al padre de un elemento generado dinamicamente jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

No puedo acceder al padre de un elemento generado dinámicamente con `jquery`:

```js
$("#test").prepend("<div class='clickame'>Hola</div>");

$(document).on("click",".clickame",function(){ 

$(this).parents("div").toggleClass("active");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

pero no me agrega el class `active` al padre.

Comment: ¿Cuál es exactamente el problema? Si declaras por ejemplo `.active{ color: red;}` en tu css y le das click al elemento con `clickame` te agrega la clase bien.

Comment: Tal como dice @JaimeMenéndez tu código de esta pregunta funciona bien. Sí que se agrega/elimna la clase `active` sobre el padre cada vez que se pulsa sobre el texto `Hola`.  Lo único que se me ocurre es que no te des cuenta porque el `active` no tenga ningún efecto visual en la página donde lo estas haciendo, pero si miras el código fuente pulsando el botón derecho sobre el texto `Hola` y seleccionando **Inspeccionar** en tu navegador, y lo haces varias veces verás como se agrega o elimina esa clase sobre el padre en la ventana del inspector.

Comment: es bastante extraño porque yo lo hago en mi proyecto y no funciona, voy a editar la pregunta con mi codigo real

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que te falte definir el atributo `class` en el div padre.

No sé tu estructura padre e hijos pero esto es a modo de prueba que así funciona.

**Editado**: Es lo mismo, esté donde esté la clase `clickame`, o venga del script o sea estático, siempre y cuándo dentro del padre, funcionará igual. Por lo menos a mí y aquí funciona bien (Debes ver si no hay algún conflicto o llaves sin cerrar o algo en jQuery).

```js
$("#test").prepend("<div class='clickame'>Hola</div>");

$("#test").on("click",".clickame",function(){
 
 $(this).parents("div").toggleClass("active");

});
```

```css
.padre {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
}

.padre.active {
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" class="padre">

  <div id="test" class="hola ">
 
    <!-- <button class="clickame">clickame</button>-->
 
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: aca no estas creando un elemento dinamico solo estas trabajando sobre elementos estaticos es decir que ya existian en el DOM, a lo que yo me refiero es a acceder al padre de un elemento creado con jquery